# Kusto query - Return top 5 per day by category

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to count each ocurrence of "name" by "headsection" and "day"

Let's say I have the following table structure (a small snippet):

| Timestamp | Headsection | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | A |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | AA |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | AAA |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | B |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | BB |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | BBB |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | C |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | CC |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | CCC |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | D |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | CC |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | DDD |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | E |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | DD |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | EEE |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | A |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | EE |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | DDD |

In essence, I want to count the top 5 names by each day by headsection

So with 3 headsections - Each day in a year should contain 15 rows

For visualising, I want to summarize the table as such:

| Timestamp | Headsection | Name | Name_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | C | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | D | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | E | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | CC | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | AA | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | BB | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | DD | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | EE | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | DDD | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | AAA | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | BBB | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | CCC | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | EEE | 1 |

I've set the query to

```
|where timestamp between (startofday(datetime(2021-01-01)) .. endofday(now()))
```

Which means that the query should be able to turn an input table to the output table for each day up until now.

In example, the following 15 rows should be 01/02/2021 (January 2nd), with top 5 "names" *that* day by headsection.

I'm almost new to KQL, so I could really need some help!

I've tried experimented with top-nested and the summarize operator, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand how the input you provided leads to the output you expect. Please explain (or if the output doesn't match the input, please update them). Also, please don't use the same "string" everywhere, as it makes it harder to understand your query's logic.  Once done, please ping me by adding a comment here.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for looking at my question! I've updated the table and added some explanation - Hope it suffices! If it doesn't, then comment here, and I'll do my best to explain

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, it's much clearer now. I've posted an answer. Please let me know if you need any clarifications. P.S.  Going forward, please post sample input data in datatable format (like I did below), so that it would be easy to copy-paste and start working on the query, instead of spending time typing your data, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let NumItemsByDayAndHeadsection = 5;
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Headsection:long, Name:string) [
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "A",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "AA",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "AAA",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "B",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "BB",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "BBB",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "C",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "CC",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "CCC",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "D",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "DD",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "DDD",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "E",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "EE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "EEE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "A",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "EE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "DDD"
]
| summarize NameCount = count() by Timestamp, Headsection, Name
| order by Headsection asc, NameCount desc
| summarize make_list(Timestamp, NumItemsByDayAndHeadsection), make_list(Name, NumItemsByDayAndHeadsection), make_list(NameCount, NumItemsByDayAndHeadsection) by Timestamp, Headsection
| mv-expand list_Timestamp, list_Name, list_NameCount
| project Timestamp, Headsection, Name = list_Name, NameCount = list_NameCount
```

Output:

| Timestamp | Headsection | Name | NameCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | C | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | D | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | E | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | EE | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | AA | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | BB | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | CC | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | DD | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | DDD | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | AAA | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | BBB | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | CCC | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | EEE | 1 |

Comment: Hi again! Initially I couldn't get your method to work - App Insights kept giving me error messages, which i found really weird. But by changing the timespan to only cover aprrox. two months it worked perfectly! Maybe it's a limitation thing, but now I can simply replicate the query for the different months! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another altenrative is using the [top-nested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topnestedoperator) operator was created specifically for this.

```
let NumItemsByDayAndHeadsection = 5;
datatable(Timestamp: datetime, Headsection: long, Name: string) [
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "A",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "AA",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "AAA",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "B",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "BB",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "BBB",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "C",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "CC",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "CCC",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "D",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "DD",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "DDD",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "E",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "EE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "EEE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 1, "A",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 2, "EE",
    datetime(2021-01-01), 3, "DDD"
]
| top-nested of Timestamp by Dummy=max(1), 
top-nested of Headsection by Dummy2=max(1), 
top-nested 5 of Name by Count=count()
| project Timestamp, Headsection, Name, Count
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I made it work with Slavik N's query, but if I get the time I'll see if this method works as well! Thanks!

Comment: @ThreeFiberBars, I think Rony's answer is more efficient than mine. You wrote that mine fails if you run it for a period longer than two months, please try Rony's suggestion instead. If his query runs while my fails, please accept Rony's answer instead of mine. Thanks!

Comment: Okay! I'll give it a shot!